# Does import a module inside a function creates a problem?

Tags: python

```
def my_func(text):
    import my_module

    return my_module.compute(text)
```

I run my program and it seems it's fine. I am afraid the class in my_module may be initialized multiple times for each, but the logging message in the initializer shows it is only initialized once.

Is this a good way for lazy initialization?

Comment: yap, you can do in crazy way, but according to the PEP - 8 standards, better way is placing all modules at top of the file.

Comment: @SaisivaA -  a counter example is a slow loading module like pandas that isn't always used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good way to do lazy initialization. Python only imports a module once. After that its in `sys.modules` and the check to see if the module is loaded is fast.

If the module is always imported, put it at the top of the module. If the importing function is called extremely often then there may be a call to do it outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Its generally considered good practice to import all modules at the very beginning of the program. It's best to do this as it not only keeps all the modules together and looking cleaner, but it also allows you to access classes and methods inside of that python module elsewhere in your program, rather than just in that function's scope.

Comment: Unless the module isn't always used and I think that is what OP may be implying with "lazy initialization"

Comment: The reason for my lazy initialization is that, in this module there are a few functions, only this function needs to use the imported module, so I think lazy initialization is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Don't see anything strange in it:

```py
import sys                                                                        

def func(v):                                                                      
    from math import sqrt                                                         

    return sqrt(v)                                                                

def main():                                                                       
    for i in range(1000):                                                         
        func(i * i)                                                               

    print([m for m in sys.modules.keys()].\                                       
        count("math"))                                                            

if __name__ == "__main__":                                                        
    main()
```

Output:

```
1
```

What profiler says:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 temp.py:2(<module>)
```

These are cProfile feature. Nonetheless, `sqrt` is imported exactly once.